# Modify Subject, Body after message_from_string in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to modify an email2sms script for Smstools 3.

A sample incoming sms file:

```
$ cat /var/spool/sms/incoming/GSM1.AtEO8G
From: 950
From_TOA: D0 alphanumeric, unknown
From_SMSC: 421950900050
Sent: 17-09-13 17:41:17
Received: 17-09-13 17:48:21
Subject: GSM1
Modem: GSM1
IMSI: 231030011459971
Report: no
Alphabet: ISO
Length: 5

test1
```

The script is using the following code to format the message:

```
if (statuscode == 'RECEIVED'):
    smsfile = open(smsfilename)
    msg = email.message_from_string(smsfile.read())
    msg['Original-From'] = msg['From']
    msg['To'] = forwardto
```

The problem: I want to modify Subject field in the code above. I tried something `msg['Subject '] = 'Example'` (after msg['To']), but the Subject field is not overwrited, but doubled. Anybody knows how to modify this after `email.message_from_string()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace `Subject` header for message.

```
msg.replace_header('Subject', 'Example Subject')
```

Assigning to an index always adds a new header. Only use when header doesn't exist.

```
msg['Subject'] = 'Example Subject' # add new subject header
print(msg.items)

>> [('From', '950'), ('From_TOA', 'D0 alphanumeric, unknown'), 
    ('From_SMSC', '421950900050'), ('Sent', '17-09-13 17:41:17'), 
    ('Received', '17-09-13 17:48:21'), ('Subject', 'GSM 1'),
    ('Modem', 'GSM1'), ('IMSI', '231030011459971'), 
    ('Report', 'no'), ('Alphabet', 'ISO'),
    ('Length', '5'), ('Original-From', '950'),
    ('Subject', 'Example Subject')]
```